# Apache Camel choice() and doTry() don't seem to work together

Tags: apache-camel

When I define a route (snippet) like this:

```
.doTry()
    .choice()
        .when(header("s").isEqualTo(1))
            .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "normal")
    .endChoice()
.doCatch(Exception.class)
    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "exception")
.endDoTry()
```

I am getting a `Cannot resolve method doCatch(...)` error in my IDE (IntelliJ).

Am I not allowed to put `choice` predicates within `doTry()`?

Comment: theorically, you should use `end()` instead of `endChoice()` in this case.. but this doesn't resolve your issue as the end() method doesn't return a typed processor definition.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
.doTry()
    .choice()
        .when(header("s").isEqualTo(1))
            .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "normal")
    .endDoTry()
.doCatch(Exception.class)
    .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "exception")
.end()
```

I was making the same error as you not so long ago; "endDoTry" sounds like "end the doTry block" but I think it should in fact be read as "end whatever the current block is and go back to the enclosing try definition".

The same applies to "endChoice".

Answer (score 0):

This works.. but honestly, I don't think it's a good answer :

```
((TryDefinition) from("direct:yo").doTry()
        .choice()
            .when(header("s").isEqualTo(1))
                .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "normal")
            .end())
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "exception")
        .endDoTry();
```

Comment: Am I trying to do something the wrong way?  Usually when the answer is dubious, the question is flawed.

Comment: You should maybe post to the official mailing list. It's look like a bug to me but I can't explain why this isn't known, so I must be wrong!